# Stack permutations sorted in lexicographical order

Tags: algorithm, math, stack, permutation

A stack permutation of number N is defined as the number of sequences which you can print by doing the following

1. Keep two stacks say A and B.
2. Push numbers from 1 to N in reverse order in B. (so the top of B is 1 and the last element in B is N)
3. Do the following operations

- Choose the top element from A or B and print it and delete it (pop it). This can be done on a non-empty stack only.
- Move the top element from B to A (if B is non-empty)
- If both stacks are empty then stop

All possible sequences obtained by doing these operations in some order are called `stack permutations`.

eg: N = 2
stack permutations are (1, 2) and (2, 1)
eg: N = 3
stack permutations are (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1) and (3, 2, 1)

The number of stack permutations for N numbers is C(N), where C(N) is the Nth `Catalan Number`.

Suppose we generate all stack permutations for a given N and then print them in lexicographical order (dictionary order), how can we determine the kth permutation, without actually generating all the permutations and then sorting them?

I want some algorithmic approaches that are programmable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say whether `k` should be 0 based or 1 based.  I chose 0.  Switching back is easy.

The approach is to first write a function to be able to count how many stack permutations there are from a given decision point.  Use memoization to make it fast.  And then proceed down the decision tree by skipping over decisions that lead to permutations which are lexicographically smaller.  That will lead to the list of decisions that are the one you want.

```py
def count_stack_permutations (on_b, on_a=0, can_take_from_a=True, cache={}):
    key = (on_b, on_a, can_take_from_a)
    if on_a < 0:
        return 0 # can't go negative.
    elif on_b == 0:
        if can_take_from_a:
            return 1 # Just drain a
        else:
            return 0 # Got nothing.
    elif key not in cache:
        # Drain b
        answer = count_stack_permutations(on_b-1, on_a, True)
        # Drain a?
        if can_take_from_a:
            answer = answer + count_stack_permutations(on_b, on_a-1, True)
        # Move from b to a.
        answer = answer + count_stack_permutations(on_b-1, on_a+1, False)
        cache[key] = answer

    return cache[key]

def find_kth_permutation (n, k):
    # The end of the array is the top
    a = []
    b = list(range(n, 0, -1))
    can_take_from_a = True # We obviously won't first. :-)

    answer = []
    while 0 < max(len(a), len(b)):
        action = None
        on_a = len(a)
        on_b = len(b)

        # If I can take from a, that is always smallest.
        if can_take_from_a:
            if count_stack_permutations(on_b, on_a - 1, True) <= k:
                k = k - count_stack_permutations(on_b, on_a - 1, True)
            else:
                action = 'a'
        # Taking from b is smaller than digging into b so I can take deeper.
        if action is None:
            if count_stack_permutations(on_b-1, on_a, True) <= k:
                k = k - count_stack_permutations(on_b-1, on_a, True)
            else:
                action = 'b'
        # Otherwise I will move.
        if action is None:
            if count_stack_permutations(on_b-1, on_a, False) < k:
                return None # Should never happen
            else:
                action = 'm'

        if action == 'a':
            answer.append(a.pop())
            can_take_from_a = True
        elif action == 'b':
            answer.append(b.pop())
            can_take_from_a = True
        else:
            a.append(b.pop())
            can_take_from_a = False
    return answer

# And demonstrate it in action.
for k in range(0, 6):
    print((k, find_kth_permutation(3, k)))
```

Comment: Its possible to post the unrank function to?

Comment: @TThoEinthausend I would have to write it.  But that would be a question of figuring out which decision came next, then counting how many you skipped over.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using factoradic(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system)

If you need quick solution in Java use JNumberTools

```
JNumberTools.permutationsOf("A","B","C")
                .uniqueNth(4) //next 4th permutation
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This API will generate the next nth permutation directly in lexicographic order. So you can even generate next billionth permutation of 100 items.

for generating next nth permutation of given size use:

```
JNumberTools.permutationsOf("A","B","C")
                .kNth(2,4) //next 4th permutation of size 2
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

maven dependency for JNumberTools is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.deepeshpatel</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnumbertools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```